# Efficient way of finding number of divisors of a number n less than k

Tags: c++, number-theory

I have done this :-

```
int divisors(int div, int i) {

    int ans = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j * j <= div; j++) {
        if (div % j == 0) {
            if (div / j == j && j < i)ans++;
            else {
                if (j < i && div / j < i) {
                    ans += 2;
                }
                else if (j < i) {
                    ans += 1;
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ans;

}
```

however this takes O(sqrt(div)) time, i there a way to optimize this?

Comment: you only need to check the prime numbers

Comment: please add more info and what you are trying to do in this function, so we can help you out better

Comment: @AlanBirtles could you provide a link or something for me to check that?

Comment: @TharunK im trying to find the number of divisors of a number n that are less than a number k. for example i could find divisors of 12 less than 5, they wld be 1,2,3 and 4.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-divisors-natural-number-set-1/ ... i implemented a version of that.

Comment: Find the prime factors then the divisors are just the various permutations of the prime factors, e.g if the prime factors are 2, 2 and 3, the divisors are 2, 3, 2*2, 2*3, and 2*2*3

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what you will do with this function. If you are going to calculate the number of divisors (less than a limit) for just a few numbers then the approach of using a function like the one you present could well be the best way.

On the other hand if you want to compute this for all numbers (between some limits perhaps) then a better approach might be to calculate this rather like the sieve of Aritosthenes. That is you loop over the divisors d in range, and for each d add 1 to the count for d, 2d, ... these being the only numbers that can be divided by d.

So something along the lines of

```
void compute( int maxn, int maxd, int* counts)
{  memset( counts, 0, maxn *sizeof *counts);
   for( int d=1; d<maxd; ++d)
   {   for( int n=d; n<maxn; n+=d)
       { counts[n] += 1;
       }
   }
}
```

After calling this counts[n] will hold the number of divisors less than maxd for each n 0,..maxn-1. Note that there are no divisions or modulus operations at all in the code above; these are often much slower than other arithmetic operations.

Comment: i tried the sieve method too but that didnt work either, still too slow. I was hoping to find a method which would let me calculate the number of divisors faster than sqrt(n) time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot go lower than `O(sqrt(N))` because in the worst case you take `k = N`, that time you'll have to traverse till `sqrt(N)`

Comment: Yes i think so too, but the question i wanna solve requires me to calculate it faster

Comment: what are the constraints, if the constraints allow, you can calculate sieve of Eratosthenes once, and use it multiple time for different values of `N` and `K`, the time complexity after tat becomes `O(n^1/3)` for each iteration of `N` and `K`